# How do I get the path from MATLAB?

Tags: matlab, user-interface, matlab-guide

I want to implement a GUI environment in MATLAB. I want to use the Browser button to load a file, then input the file into the code I want to use and output it. Help.

```matlab
% --- Executes on button press in pushbutton1.
function pushbutton1_Callback(~, ~, handles)
% hObject    handle to pushbutton1 (see GCBO)
% eventdata  reserved - to be defined in a future version of MATLAB
% handles    structure with handles and user data (see GUIDATA)
[filename, pathname] = uigetfile({'*.txt'},'File Selector');
fullpathname = strcat(pathname, filename);
text = fileread(fullpathname);
set(handles.text2, 'String', fullpathname)


% --- Executes on button press in pushbutton2.
function pushbutton2_Callback(~, ~, handles)
% hObject    handle to pushbutton2 (see GCBO)
% eventdata  reserved - to be defined in a future version of MATLAB
% handles    structure with handles and user data (see GUIDATA)
[filename, pathname] = uigetfile({'*.txt'},'File Selector');
fullpathname = strcat(pathname, filename);
text = fileread(fullpathname);
set(handles.text3, 'String', fullpathname)


% --- Executes on button press in pushbutton3.
function pushbutton3_Callback(~, ~, handles)
% hObject    handle to pushbutton3 (see GCBO)
% eventdata  reserved - to be defined in a future version of MATLAB
% handles    structure with handles and user data (see GUIDATA)
[filename, pathname] = uigetfile({'*.txt'},'File Selector');
fullpathname = strcat(pathname, filename);
text = fileread(fullpathname);
set(handles.text4, 'String', fullpathname)

D1=load('text2');
D1=D1';
D1=reshape(D1,l1*l2,1);

%% D2,D3 매트릭스 direct데이터 파일

D2=load('text3');
D3=load('text4');
```

Answer (score 0):

You used

```
  set(handles.text2, 'String', fullpathname)
```

so in the routine that needs the name, you can use

```
 get(handles.text2, 'String')
```

Answer (score 0):

All three of your callbacks already do exactly what you want to do:

1. When the user pushes the button that has one of the callbacks assigned they open the file explorer where the user can select a file.
2. They save the path in a `fullpathname` variable
3. They assign the text to the `String` property of the handles `text2`, `text3` or `text4`.

So now there are several reasons why this could fail to work as you expect:

- None of your callback functions is assigned to user interface element of your GUI. You can simply check this if you open your GUI in the Matlab GUIDE feature, right click on one of the buttons and check the property inspector. There should be an entry that looks like this:

[image: How the property inspector should look like]

- None of the handles `text2`, `text3` or `text4` exist. So Matlab does not know where to assign the text. You can get a overview of all elements by using the Object browser in the upper menu:

[image: Object Browser]

- `fileread` is not able to read the content of your files. You could check this by making sure `fileread` is working on your files with a simple non-GUI script.